# jQuery image rotator with multiple instances on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-rotation

Good day,

I've searched and researched this for the past 12 hours and can't find a solution to my problem. And because I'm not too clued up on Javascript and jQuery I'm not exactly sure what to look for and search for.

I've implemented this [jQuery Image Rotator](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html) on my site successfully and its working brilliantly with one instance of the rotator working on a page. Now, I want to know if its possible to get more than one rotator working on a single page, at the same time.

My efforts so far haven't been successful. The two rotators will load properly, but the first image of the first rotator will start playing. And then, will switch over to the second rotator and continue rotating that one, while the first one is left blank.

Any help and direction on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: could you show us your code ... the html rendered and the javascript you initialize it. it would help. though 1 of the things that pops in my mind would be, check if both rotators don't have the same ID, ID's need to be unique in a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is currently implemented, no. The rotator code explicitly operates on the contents of whatever matches `div#rotator`, which *should* be at most one element.

Doing something like the following would do the trick - pass in the `id` of the div containing the `ul`.

```
function theRotator( id ) {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    var jqElem = $( '#' + id );
    jqElem.find('ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    jqElem.find('ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval(rotate,6000);

    function rotate() { 
        //Get the first image
        var current = (jqElem.find('ul li.show')?  jqElem.find('ul li.show') : jqElem.find('ul li:first'));

        //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
        var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? jqElem.find('ul li:first') :current.next()) : jqElem.find('ul li:first'));   

        //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
        next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

        //Hide the current image
        current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
        .removeClass('show');

    };

}


$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator( <id of rotator container 1> );
    theRotator( <id of rotator container 2> );
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gustav! As I understand it, do I just put in the ID of the div in "theRotator();" at the end and change nothing else?

Comment: Hi Sam! Replace the function definition of `theRotator` with the one given here. Also, note that I've relocated the function `rotate()` - it is now found _inside_ `theRotator`. Essentially, the effect of this is that each instance of `theRotator` sees its own `rotate` function, which in turn makes use of the outer function's `jqElem` variable.  Make sure that the HTML is structured identically for each rotator (except for the containers' `id`, of course) and that the CSS actually applies to all rotators - e.g. using `class="rotator"` on the container.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I'm sounding really dumb here. When you say replace the function definition of `theRotator`, do you mean the the ones within `$(document).ready(function()`? What about `function theRotator( id )`?

Comment: Assuming that you're using the markup, style and JS from the page you linked to, simple replace all contents of the `script` tag with the code above.

Comment: I am using the same markup as what I've looked to yes. I've copied and pasted the code above into a new .js file and linked to it in the head. I'm just slightly confused as to where and how to out in the div's id.

Comment: It's probably easier for you to look at it like this (working fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/vjP4A/3/

Comment: That is absolutely insane! Thank you so much for your help!! I think my mind has been made mush trying to figure this out =].